# Problem with using Join operator in Lambda Expression and Expression Tree

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda, c#-3.0, expression-trees

I write this method:

```
public List<TResult2> SelectAndJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult, TResult2>(IEnumerable<TInner> inner, 
                                                                      System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Regions, TKey>> outerKeySelector, 
                                                                      System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> innerKeySelector, 
                                                                      System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Regions, TInner, TResult>> resultSelector,
                                                                      Func<Regions, TResult2> selector)
    {
        using (RepositoryDataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
                return RepositoryDataContext.Regions.Join(inner, outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, resultSelector).AsEnumerable<TResult2>().Select<Regions, TResult2>(selector).ToList<TResult2>();

        }
    }
```

but the expression follow return has this Error:

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.AsEnumerable(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

How I can get rid of this error?

is this code standard?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing the point... but:

`IQueryable` inherits from `IEnumerable` so I think that `AsEnumerable()` is unnecessary in this code.

If you really do need/want to execute the query before doing the `Select`, then you could use `ToList()` instead of `AsEnumerable()` - this would be clearer

I'm also wondering if you are including `using System.Linq` in your .cs file - as `AsEnumerable()` is an extension method within `System.Linq`

Comment: `AsEnumerable()` is a neccessary step to be able to do Linq to Objects queries on top of a Linq to Entities/SQL query

Comment: This is not about `using`, he would have different error in that case.

Comment: I think the point is Join return a custom projection and it must be AsEnumerable<TResult>().I must test it and write here the result.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `AsEnumerable<TResult2>` on enumerable which will be of type `IQueryable<TResult>`. You should call `AsEnumerable<TResult>` or you can even omit generic parameter and call `AsEnumerable()`

Also your next select will not work for the same reason - you are providing wrong types for generics.